# Django permissions analysis

Tags: django, django-permissions

Is anyone aware of a programmatic way of analysing a codebase to see which permissions each view is protected by?

I'd like to be able to run a regular report on a site to inform us which views are available and who can see them etc. rather than having to maintain a list by hand.

I'm aware of the show_urls command from django-extensions but that doesn't help with the permissions side of things.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't an easy way to do this.

One of the problems is that it's hard to introspect a view that uses the `permission_required` decorator to tell which permissions it needs. If you only use class based views, then it would be easier, since you set `permission_required` when using the `PermissionRequiredMixin`.

On [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-developers/rpTh4G3BgIQ/NI1AhhAJBgAJ) on the django-developers mailing list, I suggested that the permission required decorator could set an attribute, for example `_permissions_required` (perhaps `permissions_required` would be better as it's consistent with the mixin). However the idea hasn't been taken any further as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Well all of our code uses CBVs now so it might work. But my problem is even greater, as I use django-guardian for object-based permissions too so there's a lot more to it than just permission_required.